# Can't run Kotlin programs on the command line

Tags: kotlin, cmd

I have downloaded the kotlin compiler 1.2.21 zip file, extracted it to C:\Program files\ and also added the bin folder in the system PATH variable. I had already installed and configured JDK.

I wrote a simple program, saved it in C:\USERS\USER\ with the name args.kts and ran it in cmd with this command : `kts args.kts Hello`

But I am getting this error every time :

```
exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 11052 out of bounds for length 11052
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUnsignedShort(ClassReader.java:2464)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(ClassReader.java:2525)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:761)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:646)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:507)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.modules.JavaModuleInfo$Companion.read(JavaModuleInfo.kt:67)                                                       at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder.findSystemModule(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder.access$findSystemModule(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:25)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder$systemModules$1.invoke(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:37)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder$systemModules$1.invoke(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:25)                                         at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:149)                          at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:109)
        at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:133)
        at kotlin.sequences.FlatteningSequence$iterator$1.ensureItemIterator(Sequences.kt:254)
        at kotlin.sequences.FlatteningSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:241)
        at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.none(_Sequences.kt:1239)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.addModularRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:227)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.computeRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:124)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.convertClasspathRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:79)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:230)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:409)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:286)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createEnvironmentWithScriptingSupport(K2JVMCompiler.kt:276)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:170)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:109)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:53)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:70)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:36)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:157)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:148)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt:343)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader.run(Preloader.java:81)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader.main(Preloader.java:43)
```

FYI, I followed this site : http://otfried.org/courses/cs109/project-install.html

This is my code inside the **args.kts** file which was provided in the above mentioned site :

```
println("Your arguments are:")

for (i in 0 until args.size) {
  println("$i: ${args[i]}")
}
```

Please tell me what to do.

Comment: The error seems to be with your program instead of the Kotlin compiler itself. Can you post a reference to your simple program?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions for the "Manual Install"
at [Working with the Command Line Compiler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html) .

If you need the Kotlin REPL, install Kotlin 1.3.31 - [1.3.40 crashes](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32085).

Worked perfectly on my Lubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I have no Windows to try it. Sorry.
But it's a tutorial by JetBrains. They should know.
Besides, you can find more of their documentation and tutorials there.
Good luck and happy learning !

Comment: As you have said, I had downloaded, extracted and included the path of the Kotlin compiler 1.3.40 in the PATH variable. But now I can't even run the `kotlinc` command, it is showing exceptions.

Comment: Install 1.3.31, not 1.3.40. I updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: That "little detail" was in [my answer] (stackoverflow.com/a/56810758/11713766) to your other Kotlin compiler question. But I forgot to mention it here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Benjamin Charais] (https://stackoverflow.com/users/7729375/benjamin-charais) is right.

There are args.size arguments. So your loop should be:

for (i in 0 until (args.size - 1)) { ...

Sorry, I wasted your time before.